# Query does not Insert. CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter and am trying to debug insert code that is not working and i cannot seem to find the error. According to the MVC guide in codeigniter documentation I think the code is fine. Please help me out.

here is my code:

**Function linked with the view**

```
function submit_details() {
        $fullname = $this->input->post('fullname');
        $names = explode(" ", $fullname);
        $firstname = $names[0];
        $lastname = $names[1];
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $country = $this->input->post('country');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $password = $this->_encrypt_pass($password);
        $time = time();
        $activation = $this->_encrypt_pass($time . ' ' . $fullname);

        $new_user_data = array(
            'firstname' => $firstname,
            'lastname' => $lastname,
            'password' => $password,
            'email' => $email,
            'country' => $country,
            'activation' => $activation,
            'creationdate' => $time,
            'updatedate' => $time,
            'usertype' => 1,
            'status' => 0
        );

        if ($this->users->create_user($new_user_data)) {
            # Create User Default group
            $user = $this->users->get_user_by_email($email);

            $userid = $user->userid;
            $groupname = 'General';
            $groupdesc = 'General Group for contacts.';


            $group = array(
                'user' => $userid,
                'groupdesc' => $groupdesc,
                'groupname' => $groupname
            );

            $this->contacts_model->CreateContactGroup($group);

            // echo "Account creation for $fullname succesfull. An Activation link has been sent to your email ($email)account";
        }
        redirect('login', $msg = 'Account creation for $fullname succesfull. An Activation link has been sent to your email ($email)account');
    }
```

**Function that inserts**

```
function create_user($user) {
        $result = false;
        if (!$this->check_email_exists($user['email'])) {
            if ($this->send_activation_link($user)) {
                $this->db->insert('users', $user);
            }
            $result = true;
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: You're currently redirecting the user with a success message regardless if `create_user()` was successful or not.

Comment: @magnus Eriksson thanks for the edit. Please help

Comment: What actually happens when you run this code?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the user can only be redirected if the insertion is a success. if its not , it does not redirect

Comment: That's not what the code does, since you redirect the user _after_ the if statement (which means that it will _always_ redirect the user regardless). If you put the redirect inside the if statement instead, then it will only redirect if it was successful. That way you know if `create_user()` failed or not. However, you won't know if it failed because the email exists or if the query simply failed.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson I actually found the problem is in an activation function. When a user registers and its successful, an activation link is send to them and that is not happening thereby data cannot be inserted

Comment: Can you please post the code of your activation function

Comment: @Astound I solved that too but it seems the SMTP server gives me an error 550:invalid recipient yet the email I input is actually valid

Comment: if the email address is fake then it maybe genrating error so put the if condition, if mail is send then and then insert the user.

i suggest you to use try catch that will more helpful to handles the error

which method are you using for the sending email codeigniter Library or mail() or other library

Answer (score 0):

Can You tell the error showing on console

Where are you loading the model? I guess your model is users.Load it in a constructor or in the autoload.php May be you are not loading the model

Comment: I actually found the problem is in an activation function. When a user registers and its successful, an activation link is send to them and that is not happening thereby data cannot be inserted